# Repair file diffs in git

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have a file in a git repository. When I use git diff it seems like if I did delete all the content and added again (with one line different) but when I use the Netbeans git/diff tool I see only this line as difference.

In fact, there is only one difference line. What can I do for repair the difference?

Comment: Try `git diff -w`, or some other whitespace-ignoring option.  The help for git diff explains all the options.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have changed the end of line character from unix `\n` to windows `\r\n` or vice versa.

The solution: just don't do that

Comment: Seems to be, any real way to fix it?

Comment: @José Carlos: it depends on if you have shared the changes already. Have you pushed them anywhere?

Comment: I pushed only one files (because I have several) in order to test and it confirmed that it is the way it happened.

Comment: In general, you can use Git's `smudge` and `clean` filters to deal with that problem on Windows.  But it requires forethought and planning.  You can find many tutorials about it on the Internet.